# App: installed from official Google Play Store or from disk?

Tags: android, installation, google-play

Is it possible to know if an application come (has been installed) from the official *Google Play Store* or from the disk?

Comment: I think impossible.. But i dont know about from the disk

Comment: Is this something you want to detect programmatically?

Comment: Yes, when a new version of my app is available from Play Store or from my server, I need to know if I need to run my own app updater or open the Google Play App.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you go to the play store and actually check if you have the app installed? I believe that if it got installed from the store, you would find it there, else, you might not. I'm not sure though.